# Does "GART - Geo Augmented Reality Toolkit" works in windows phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-7, geolocation, windows-phone-8, augmented-reality

I want to use GART - Geo Augmented Reality Toolkit but i dont know if I can use it in windows phone 8 or is only for windows phone 7.5. Thanks

Comment: You can build for WP7.5 and run on 8.0 devices. There should be no reason that it wouldn't - have you tried it?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't try it yet but I would.

Answer (score 0):

No problems using it for WP75/78 - Doesnt work directly as a WP8 add in, but as stated WP7 apps run fine under 8.